# Spring boot web war - web-inf/classes/context.xml file not found

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

When I deploy spring boot based project to tomcat, server is not able to find `persistence-context.xml` which is under `WEB-INF/classes`. I receive following error on tomcat console

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/persistence-context.xml]
```

I have following structure of Spring boot WS application:

```
src/main/java/hello/
                   Application.java
                   HelloWebXml.java

src/main/resources/
                   persistence-context.xml
```

Following are my classes

```
@ComponentScan("foo.bla.bar")
@ImportResource("classpath:persistence-context.xml")
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Following is the WebXml class.

```
public class HelloWebXml extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
}
}
```

Following is my `pom.xml` file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.foo.bar</groupId>
<artifactId>bar-ws</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <start-class>bla.bar.Application</start-class>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin> 
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

I am building a war file of this project. Can anyone please guide me how to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: You just need to specify the resource as `classpath:persistence-context.xml`

Comment: adding classpath creates not difference. Its the same error.

Comment: Post your `pom.xml` please. Also, how do you build the .war?

Comment: I have added pom.xml. Please have a look. Thank

Comment: you need to put the `persistence-context.xml` under the `webapp` or `web-content` folder and then use `classpath:persistence-context.xml`

Comment: @M.Sharma Placing it under webapp did solve the issue. Please add it as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`@ImportResource("classpath:persistence-context.xml")`

Will work fine just dont forget to put the `persistence-context.xml` under the webapp folder as it is considered as the classpath in case of Web Project.

Well in for placing the file under `src/main/resources` then try reading it this way you will never face path problem in this case.

```
String pathOfTheResurceFile = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                                    .getResource("yourFileName").getPath();
```

Comment: ... and why should they?  Please explain why this works

Comment: `ImportResources` usually red upto `src/main/resources` putting /makes it a directory to search its content

Comment: it does not create any difference. Still the same error.